# Trailing ToolbarItem placement on WatchOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I need a small button to be visible in most of my views, so I tried placing it in the toolbar. If I set `ToolbarItem.placement` to `.cancellationAction`, it will show left of the title, which is ok. It'd be be ideal though, if the the button would show at the trailing edge of the toolbar. When I use `.confirmationAction` to achieve this, it will show there, but be covered by the time (except on the root view! time won't show there).

```swift
.navigationTitle("A title")
.toolbar(content: {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction, content: {
        MyButton()
    })
})
```

I think it is against Apple's guidelines to hide time on WatchOS, but it wouldn't matter in my case, since the app won't be published on AppStore.

How can I place a view at the trailing edge of my WatchOS toolbar, while making sure time won't overlap it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible for watchOS 9 and earlier. With the new watchOS 10 in some months, this will be changed. You can watch the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10026/).